# Data Referencing issue while applying filter on collection - Flex

Tags: apache-flex, collections, filter

I am facing one issue regarding data referencing. I have one object having one key value pair data i.e.

```
var _dataObj:Object;

_dataObj[‘value’] = xml;
```

I retrieve data from object and apply a filter over `<PEM>` inside `<COMP>` tag. I have taken xmlList(all children of xml) from my xml and added into a xmlListCollection.

```
var _listColl:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(xml.children);
```

I have applied a filter on the collection where,

```
IsActive = ‘Y’
```

After filter my collection contains only two record, which is correct. By my expectation is that it should reflect into my `_dataObject` also. But it’s not reflecting. I don’t know why it’s getting deference and not showing filtered data into `_dataObject`.

XML Structure:

```
<comp recordId="1150">
  <pem recordId="1150">
    <ID>3125465</ID>
    <IsActive>Y</IsActive>
  </pem>
  <pem recordId="1151">
    <ID>3125466</ID>
    <IsActive>N</IsActive>
  </pem>
  <pem recordId="1152">
    <ID>3125467</ID>
    <IsActive>Y</IsActive>
  </pem>
</comp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `ArrayCollection` and `XMLListCollection` extend [ListCollectionView](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html).

As its name implies `ListCollectionView` is a 'view' on a set of data, which essentially means it can **present** the data in a different manner, e.g. by sorting it, filtering it, etc. But it leaves the underlying data untouched, which is why your original `xml` is never changed.

`ListCollectionView` has a [toArray](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#toArray%28%29) function though which will return the filtered data as a new Array instance.

Comment: My requirement is that xml should also update once my collection get filtered. So, do you want to say that what i want to achieve is not possible OR is there any alternatives ?